# facebook icon, the f in the icon should not shift up on hover (CSS @media)

Tags: html, css

I have a recording underneath that shows an issue with my social media icon. It works perfect in desktop where it rotates on hover and changes colour. For mobile I want it to work differently. I don't want it to rotate on mobile as it's just a tap so I remove the transformation and transition and change the hover color.

The issue I have which you can see in this recording is that when I tap on the button (so you can see it I tap and hold). The 'f' in the icon moves and I don't want it to move. How can this be fixed?

HTML:

```css
.social-icon {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-border-radius: 138px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 138px;
  border-radius: 138px;
  border: 5px solid;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1px;
  padding-top: 11px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.social-icon:hover {
    transform: rotate(360deg)scale(1.3);
}
/* Facebook Button Styling */
.facebook {
    font-size: 22px;
    padding-top: 9px;
    border-color: #3b5998;
    background-color: #3b5998;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.facebook:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #3b5998;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .facebook:hover {
    background-color: #627aac;
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  .social-icon {
  transition: none;
  } 
   .social-icon:hover {
   transform: none;
   }    
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" integrity="sha512-72McA95q/YhjwmWFMGe8RI3aZIMCTJWPBbV8iQY3jy1z9+bi6+jHnERuNrDPo/WGYEzzNs4WdHNyyEr/yXJ9pA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="blank" class="social-margin"> 
  <div class="social-icon facebook">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
  </div>
</a>
```

You can view the recording here: https://streamable.com/tx6xfn

Comment: Your link does not work

Comment: @MaxiGui Thanks for pointing that out, I have updated the link

Comment: When I try on codepen it seems to wrok fine with the code you gave above. You might have a rule canceling  `padding-top: 9px;`from `.facebook`

Comment: It looks to me like perhaps there are some styles affecting `:active` or `:focus` links, either in the built in stylesheet for that browser, or somewhere in your code that's not included here.

Comment: Ah ok cool, I will have a look at the in built theme css and see if anything is causing the issue Thank you both :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with **display: inline-flex;** property.
Try below snippet, I hope this will help you.

```css
.social-icon {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 138px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 22px;
}
.social-icon:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.3);
}
.facebook{
  border: 5px solid #3b5998;
  background-color: #3b5998;
}
.facebook:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #3b5998;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .social-icon {
    transition: none;
  } 
  .social-icon:hover {
    transform: none;
  } 
  .facebook:hover{
    background-color: #627aac;
    color: #ffffff;
  }   
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" integrity="sha512-72McA95q/YhjwmWFMGe8RI3aZIMCTJWPBbV8iQY3jy1z9+bi6+jHnERuNrDPo/WGYEzzNs4WdHNyyEr/yXJ9pA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="blank" class="social-icon facebook"> 
  <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```